# How to run appium testcase from command prompt in windows machine?

Tags: appium

I'm ready with Appium setup and AddContact testcase(script in java). I'm able to run successfully through eclipse and it's working fine. But, I would like to run same script on command line.

Comment: What solutions have you tried already? What exactly did not work?

Comment: Please provide more information on the code you have written? Are you using testng/junit? etc.

Comment: Currently I'm using Eclipse to execute my code and it's working. No issues in my code. I would like to execute same file(Appium Script) thorough Command prompt. Currently I'm using TestNG framework.

Comment: You can create a batch file and then execute that batch file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the command prompt on your system.
2. Go to the Test Java project folder where the new testng.xml is created.
3. Type the following line. `java -cp "/opt/testng-6.8.jar:bin" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml.`

This is the general way to run TestNG suites from command line

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Better install maven in ur machine and add maven dependancy to your project. Then you can directly use the following command to execute the test command line easily.

```
mvn clean test
```